# Prepend file by .htaccess in to specify tag

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, prepend, document-body

I have a question. So i found this article by David Walsh - [Prepend and Append Files with .htaccess](http://davidwalsh.name/prepend-append-files-htaccess). David shows how to prepend some file usuing .htaccess. I would like to know is there any option to prepend some javascript file into specify of page HTML code, f.e. in a head or just in the bottom of `body`? Thx for info.

Comment: You can include all Javascript code in the included PHP code.

Comment: Please read my question again. If i would add file in to php i can do that, i need to do this separately...

Comment: Please read my comment again. You can include your custom javascript code in the PHP file included by `php_value auto_prepend_file` directive.

Comment: So sory, I misunderstood. But im not a php guy, how to do this? Is there mayby any guide for this? Thx for help again.

Comment: Let me try it out then I will post answer here.

Comment: Posted an answer below, see if that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1: Add this in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:**

```
# Append file to bottom of page
php_value auto_append_file "includes/footer.php"
```

**Step 2: Create DOCUMENT_ROOT/includes/footer.php with this content**

```
<script>
    document.writeln('Its from javascript in footer');
    // put any JS code here
</script>
```

Comment: much thx for help, i have one more question, can i append/create this code by htaccess without including footer.php file?

Comment: I believe you cannot put JS code directly in .htaccess. It is much cleaner/safer also to include this footer line in .htaccess and then deal with changes separately in footer.php

Comment: so this code from footer.php will be included just behind of body tag close?

Comment: It is appended after main page. If main page ends with `</html>` this will be even after that. However for your purpose JS code can very well live outside `<html>` tag.